# Why values lost after break in `foreach` loop?

Tags: c#

I have a button `btnRun` to execute `timer1`. In `timer1` I want to get an id of the element, then insert values like "blah blah" into this element.

It's working.
But at second click `btnRun`, `webBrowser2.Document` lost values.
`timer` must have.

So, how to keep `webBrowser2.Document` values all time because I will click `btnRun` many times?

I only declare in top the application:

`private WebBrowser webBrowser2;`

And another button I go to link.

this.webBrowser2.Navigate("http://example.com");

```
private void btnRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.timer1.Start();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.count++;
    string str = "";
    if (this.count >= this.line.Count<string>())
    {
        this.count = 0;
        str = this.line[0];
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            str = this.line[this.count];
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
    int num = new Random().Next(0x186a0, 0x5f5e0ff);
    try
    {
        string str2;
        string str3;
        HtmlElementCollection elementsByTagName;

        int values = 0;
        values = (str.Length - str.Split(new char[] { '*' })[1].Length) - 1;
        str2 = "http://example.com" + str.Split(new char[] { '*' })[0].Substring(0, values) + "&text=*" + str.Split(new char[] { '*' })[1] + "&rand=" + num.ToString();
        str3 = this.code(str2);
        if (str3 == "")
            return;
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        MatchCollection matchs = Regex.Matches(str3, "(<a.*?>.*?</a>)", RegexOptions.Singleline);
        foreach (Match match in matchs)
        {
            if (!list.Contains(match.Groups[1].Value))
            {
                string str5 = match.Groups[1].Value;
                if (str5.Contains("javascript:foward_information"))
                {
                    string[] strArray = str5.Split(new char[] { '\'' });
                    if (strArray[3] == "0")
                    {
                        string str6 = strArray[1];
                        this.timer1.Stop();
                        this.webBrowser2.Document.GetElementById("txtCode").InnerText = str6;
                        elementsByTagName = this.webBrowser2.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");

                        foreach (HtmlElement element in elementsByTagName)
                        {
                            if (element.GetAttribute("id").Equals("cmdGit"))
                            {
                                element.InvokeMember("Click");

                                //var objWin = window.self;
                                //objWin.open('', '_self', '');
                                //objWin.close();
                            }
                        }
                        this.timer1.Stop();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: where are you populating webBrowser2 from?

Comment: @BugFinder I updated my question. I only declare: `private WebBrowser webBrowser2` and navigation to link.

Comment: "break in `foreach` loop" - what break in foreach loop? There is no break in the loop.

Comment: How do you populate the `myStringContentGetAllValueFromPage`?

Comment: The code you have posted doesn't compile.  If you have edited it for brevity you have excluded the code you require assistance with.

The loop you have posted up will always assign "blah blah" to an element with the Id txtsomay.  But only if you get a regular expression match?  I would suggest posting the complete code.

Comment: @AdamCarr I updated my question with full code.

Comment: Can I ask why are you using a Timer?  All you are doing is starting the same timer when you click the run button.  Your code is executed on the timer event.

Comment: @AdamCarr I want this auto check change of website. But when to turn off this features. The user must click button manually, but `webBrowser2` lost data after using a timer.

Comment: If you reload the page with the navigate method.  You will lose the changes made to webbroswer2.

Comment: No, I navigate to a website only one time. Not reload webBrowser2. When to click `button4` to navigate to a website.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to break the Timer, instead of break use Stop() of timer control to stop the timer.

```
 this.timer1.Stop();
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of your code is invoking a click on a button on the page. This will reload the page from the web server; by doing this it will reset any values on the page.

It is hard to give further advice as I don't understand what you're trying to do.